# Infinite periodic fraction

Tags: real-analysis

During revision I have come across a question, in a past exam paper I have the solutions to, which asks:

> Let *r* be a rational number, written as an infinite periodic fraction *r*=0.12(31), base 5. Find a representation *r*=$\frac{p}{q}$ with *p*,*q* $ \in\mathbb{N}$. You are allowed to use the decimal representation for integers *p*,*q*.

And the solution I was given is:

> 0.12(31) = $\frac{1}{5}$ + *x*, where *x* satisfies the equation $25x + x + (\frac{3}{5}+\frac{1}{25}) = x+\frac{16}{25}$. That is $x=\frac{2}{75}$(in the decimal representation). Thus, $r=\frac{7}{25}+\frac{2}{75}=\frac{23}{75}$, in the decimal representation.
>
> Optional: in base 5, one has $r=\frac{43}{300}$

I have searched online and read through the solution, but I don't even understand the question, specifically the "r=0.12(31), base 5" part, and how $\frac{23}{75}$ is equal to that. Is there a more popular term used instead of "infinite periodic fraction"?

Comment: Maybe you mean continued fraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution you were given is inelegant (to say the least). Here are two other solutions.

(1) By the definition of base-$5$ notation, the expression $r=0.12(31)=0.123131313131\dots$ base $5$ represents the real number
$$
\frac1{5^1} + \frac2{5^2} + \frac3{5^3} + \frac1{5^4} + \frac3{5^5} + \frac1{5^6} + \frac3{5^7} + \frac1{5^8} + \cdots.
$$
This can be evaluated using the geometric series formula twice:
\begin{align*}
&= \frac1{5^1} + \frac2{5^2} + \bigg( \frac3{5^3} + \frac3{5^5} + \frac3{5^7} + \cdots \bigg) + \bigg( \frac1{5^4} + \frac1{5^6} + \frac1{5^8} + \cdots \bigg) \\
&= \frac15 + \frac2{25} + \bigg( \frac{3/5^3}{1-1/5^2} \bigg) + \bigg( \frac{1/5^4}{1-1/5^2} \bigg) \\
&= \frac15 + \frac2{25} + \frac3{120} + \frac1{600} = \frac{23}{75}.
\end{align*}

(2) If $x=0.12(31)$ in base $5$, then multiplying by $5^2$ shifts the point two spots to the right: $25x=12.(31)=12.31(31)$. Subtracting (and correctly carrying in base $5$!), we get $24x = 12.31(31) - 0.12(31) = 12.14$ (where $24$ is a decimal number but $12.14$ is still written in base $5$). Converting fully to decimal,
$$
24x = 1\cdot 5 + 2 + \frac1{5} + \frac4{25} = \frac{184}{25},
$$
which gives $x=\frac{23}{75}$ as well.

Comment: The (2) solution has made it seem so simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I will add, though, that being able to understand the first sentence of solution (1) is crucial to anyone who wants to deal with base $5$ or any other bases.

Comment: I agree, I think that part was also essential to understanding how you found the final fraction in (2).

Answer (score 1):

"$r=0.12(31)$, base $5$" means that $r$ is the number whose representation in base $5$ is $0.12(31)$, where the parentheses surround the digits that repeat infinitely.

In base 10 the number becomes $0.30\overline{6}$ (the overline is another way to mark the repeating digits), which is also what you get when you calculate $\frac{23}{75}$.

Comment: In other words, $r=0.1231313131313131\dots$ in base $5$.

Comment: Yes, but avoiding the $\ldots$ to be explicit about what the repeating digits are, your number might as well be $0.123131313131313112313131313131311231313131313131\ldots$.

Comment: You can form your own opinion about whether omitting this sentence is better for teaching someone who explicitly doesn't already know what the notation means.

Comment: @GregMartin: You might have a point, but I really dislike the $\ldots$ notation.

Comment: @GregMartin I think your comment explained it well enough to me, I have learnt about recursion before, but have never seen it in this format, which was what confused me. Also, I have only briefly been taught about number bases.

Comment: @Henrik: I think it's understandable and (in some ways) good to dislike the ... notation. But let's recognize that the downsides of the ... notation have to do with rigor, not with conveying concepts. For conveying concepts it is much more accessible than other notations (which is the entire reason it is used! - humans aren't deliberately masochistic about these things).